# combine pdf files together for {pdf ver 1.7}

Tags: php, pdf, merge

I have too much pdf files and i can't change ver of pdf or buy add on for FPDI.
Is there any way for combine pdf file together **for free**?
I use this :

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

class ConcatPdf extends FPDI
{
    public $files = array();

    public function setFiles($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function concat()
    {
        foreach($this->files AS $file) {
            $pageCount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
                 $tplIdx = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
                 $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplIdx);
                 $this->AddPage($s['w'] > $s['h'] ? 'L' : 'P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
                 $this->useTemplate($tplIdx);
            }
        }
    }
}

$pdf = new ConcatPdf();
$pdf->setFiles(array("Boombastic-Box.pdf", "Fantastic-Speaker.pdf", "Noisy-Tube.pdf"));
$pdf->concat();

$pdf->Output('concat.pdf', 'I');
```

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDFMerger script
you can find it [PDF Merger](https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/)

Also you can use this below code

```
$fileArray= array("name1.pdf","name2.pdf","name3.pdf","name4.pdf");

$datadir = "save_path/";
$outputName = $datadir."merged.pdf";

$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";
//Add each pdf file to the end of the command
foreach($fileArray as $file) {
    $cmd .= $file." ";
}
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: Are you sure ? is this work for pdf ver 1.7 ? i tried it before .

Comment: FPDF error: This document (test.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.

Comment: to over come from this issue use [Ghost Script](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html). This script helps to change the PDF versions dynamically.

(1) Download the Ghostscript here.

(2) Install the Ghostscript and define the environment variable PATH.

(3) Then, use the below php code to change the PDF version.

`shell_exec( "gswin32 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=".$new_pdf." ".$old_pdf."");`

(4) Now we get PDF with version 1.4 as output, then continue with FPDF.

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes using PHP 
my code
`<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('1.pdf', 'all')
 ->addPDF('2.pdf', 'all')
 ->addPDF('7.pdf', 'all')
 ->merge('file', 'TEST2.pdf');
`